# Postgres - how do I return output to the terminal?

Tags: postgresql

I'm in the postgres terminal window and I've switched the output to a file using a command like

```
\o output.txt
```

but now I want to return the output to the terminal window, not the text file, without having to exit and log in again. How do I do that - I managed it once but can't now find it in the documentation ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html):

```
\o [ {filename | |command} ]

    Saves future query results to the file filename or pipes future results 
    into a separate Unix shell to execute command. 
    If no arguments are specified, the query output will be reset to the 
    standard output.
```

(Emphasis mine)